# CakePHP Canonical Tag with html helper

Tags: cakephp, canonical-link

How can I create this using the html helper? (with inline=false so i can specify it on a per-view basis)

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/product.php?item=swedish-fish" />
```

Can't seem to find anything on this, apart from a patch that doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found this in CakePHP bugtracking site : http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/1063-support-for-custom-meta-tag-elements-in-htmlhelper

Apparently you can use

```
echo $this->Html->meta('canonical', 'http:://example.com', array('rel'=>'canonical', 'type'=>null, 'title'=>null));
//outputs <link href="http:://example.com" rel="canonical" />
```

Answer (score 8):

It seems my friend just told me that I told him how to do this a few months back, problem solved...

```
<?php echo $this->Html->meta('canonical', 
    'http://www.example.com/product.php?item=swedish-fish', 
    array('rel'=>'canonical', 'type'=>null, 'title'=>null, 'inline' => false)
);?>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for something that automatically outputs the current url into a canonical tag, you can use the `$this->Html->url(null, true);` or `$this->here;` within the Cakephp html helper.

```
<?php echo $this->Html->meta('canonical', $this->Html->url(null, true), array('rel'=>'canonical', 'type'=>null, 'title'=>null)); ?>
```

Or

```
<?php echo $this->Html->meta('canonical', $this->here, array('rel'=>'canonical', 'type'=>null, 'title'=>null)); ?>
```

***WARNING:***
I have heard of some cases where `$this->here` has issues on local dev environments.

Answer (score 1):

In CakePHP 2:

```
echo $this->Html->meta('canonical', 'http://example.com', array('rel' => 'canonical', 'type' => null, 'title' => null, 'inline' => false));
```

In CakePHP 3:

```
echo $this->Html->meta('canonical', 'http://example.com', array('rel' => 'canonical', 'type' => null, 'title' => null, 'block' => true));
```

Note that the main difference between versions is that CakePHP 2 uses `'inline' => false` whereas CakePHP 3 uses `'block' => true` to place these within the document `<head>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

In **CakePHP 4**:

In your view (es: Articles/view.php) add this:

```
<?php $this->Html->meta(
  'canonical',
  Router::url(['controller' => 'Articles', 'action' => 'view', $article->slug], true),
  [
    'block' => true
  ]
);
?>
```

Then you print it in your layout/default.ctp with this instruction

```php
<?= $this->fetch('meta') ?>
```